# Have any of Maryam Mirzakhani's doodles been preserved?

Tags: soft-question

I edit a [magazine for High School students](http://www.pims.math.ca/resources/publications/pi-sky), and would very much like to get hold of a large image of one of the large sheets of paper with Maryam Mirzakhani's mathematical drawings on for the cover of the magazine (the sheets of paper like those that appear in, for example, [Quanta](https://d2r55xnwy6nx47.cloudfront.net/uploads/2014/08/hyperbolic-surfaces2.jpg)). I imagine that these could be of considerable historical interest. Does anyone know if any of them have been preserved?

I acknowledge that this is not a standard question for MO - if people have a better suggestion of where it should be posted, I'd be grateful to hear.

Comment: Prof. Alex Wright has a high-resolution image on his [web site](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~alexmw/mirzakhani/) --- it only shows a small portion of a larger sheet, but you might want to ask if the full image is available.

Comment: (Not related to the question.) Out of curiosity, I had a look at the latest issue, and I’m puzzled: how are the students supposed to show the false statement that “the equation $15x^2+y^2=4n$ has positive integer solutions for any integer $n\ge2$”?

Comment: Presumably you could ask her husband: https://theory.stanford.edu/~jvondrak/

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: That's embarrassing. This turns out to have been a typesetting error. The original asked students to show that $15x^2+y^2=4^n$ has a positive integer solution.

Comment: Ah, this is it! Thank you. I suspected it was a typo, but couldn’t figure out any reasonable-sounding problem that might have been intended.

Comment: Perhaps of interest: you can see her "doodling" in this [youtube video (at 2:28)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swLWqlKMl5M&t=2m28s).

Comment: The Google image search for "Maryam Mirzakhani doodles" turns up a number of them.